# When updating dataframe, date type changes to int type

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I seem to have a problem when updating my Dataframe table using this

```
Table.update(other)
```

'Table' and 'other' have the exact same column labels.
it used to work just fine, but now it started showing this for example:

```
2021-04-12T00:00:00.000000000 <class 'numpy.datetime64'>
1618185600000000000 <class 'int'>
```

the first result is taken from "other" and after update, it becomes int as seen above.

These are the results of Table.dtypes:

```
ID                      object
Column1                 object
Column2                 object
Column3                 object
Column4                 object
Column5                 object
Column6                 object
Column7                 object
dtype: object
```

And the results of other.dtypes

```
ID                            object
Column1                       float64
Column2                       datetime64[ns]
Column3                       datetime64[ns]
Column4                       float64
Column5                       datetime64[ns]
Column6                       datetime64[ns]
Column7                       object
dtype: object
```

Comment: could you please let us know the results of `print(Table.dtypes)` and `print(other.dtypes)`

Comment: @PaulBrennan, please find the results in the edited post

Answer (score 0):

When updating a dataframe with another dataframe you need to have them being the same dtype in the columns.

`to_numeric()` - provides functionality to safely convert non-numeric types (e.g. strings) to a suitable numeric type. (See also `to_datetime()` and `to_timedelta()`.)

`astype()` - convert (almost) any type to (almost) any other type (even if it's not necessarily sensible to do so). Also allows you to convert to categorial types (very useful).

`infer_objects()` - a utility method to convert object columns holding Python objects to a pandas type if possible.

`convert_dtypes()` - convert DataFrame columns to the "best possible" dtype that supports `pd.NA` (pandas' object to indicate a missing value).

see [Change column type in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-in-pandas) for more information on these instructions

*However* you need to convert the columns to dates. specifically datetime64[ns] for this you need

```
df['Column2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column2'])
df['Column3'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column3'])
df['Column5'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column5'])
df['Column6'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column6'])
```

remember to not update until they both have the same dtypes